# Jupyter Notebook Preloader using HTML

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

To start, I know very little about HTML programming and pretty much exclusively work in python.

***TLDR:*** **I need a preloader that starts when I run the first cell of my notebook and goes away when the final cell is executed.**

I'm currently working on a project and I have an idea but cannot get it to work correctly.

The idea is that I want to add a preloader when I run the first cell of my code, then when the final cell executes, I want to stop the preloader which will display all the content.

I have used preloaders before when converting my notebooks to HTML, but I have never tried to embed a preloader in a notebook. My pre-loader code is based on the one here [Preloader](https://chris-said.io/2016/02/13/how-to-make-polished-jupyter-presentations-with-optional-code-visibility/).

If I use exactly this code, the problem seems to be that since it uses $(window).load(function(), it causes a persistent preloader that doesn't disappear because it never recognizes the window being finished loading.

I have adapted the code from the link above to this (see below), but the problem is that it goes away instantly. Anyone know how to make this work?

Thanks!

```
from IPython.display import HTML,display,Markdown
display(HTML('''
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow');
  });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
  div#preloader { position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 999;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: visible;
      background: #fff url('https://faviconer.net/preloaders/245/Loading%20progress.gif') no-repeat center center;
  }

</style>

<div id="preloader"></div>
'''))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works but it's not quite what I want because the outputs are still showing while the preloader is running but it will work for now.

**First Cell of NB:**

```
from IPython.display import HTML,display,Markdown
display(HTML('''
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#preloader');
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
  div#preloader { position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 999;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: visible;
      background: #fff url('https://faviconer.net/preloaders/245/Loading%20progress.gif') no-repeat center center;
  }

</style>

<div id="preloader"></div>
'''))
```

**Last Cell of NB:**

```
display(HTML('''
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#preloader').hide();
});
</script>
'''))
```

I was using the following to hide outputs but it actually hides the preloader as well so it doesn't work.
**Beginning of NB:**

```
display(HTML('''<script>
out_show=true; 
function out_toggle() {
    if (out_show){
 $('div.output').hide();
 } else {
 $('div.output').show();
 }
 out_show = !out_show
} 
$( document ).ready(out_toggle);
</script>'''))
```

**End of NB:**

```
display(HTML('''<script>
$( document ).ready(out_toggle);
</script>
'''))
```

**Please feel free to let me know if y'all have any better solutions :)**